# How would I nest file path strings into a list based upon matching folder paths in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

I just asked a similar question, however this is a bit different.

This time I'm trying to basically create a nested file tree structure in a list. Lets say I have this list:

```
files = [
'user/hey.jpg',
'user/folder1/1.txt',
'user/folder1/folder2/random.txt,'
'user/folder1/blah.txt',
'user/folder3/folder4/folder5/1.txt',
'user/folder3/folder4/folder5/3.txt',
'user/folder3/folder4/folder5/2.txt',
'user/1.jpg'
]
```

Im looking to get this output (not concerned about the order), I may not have formatted this list correctly but here is a general concept:

```
['user'['1.jpg','hey.jpg','folder1'['1.txt','blah.txt','folder2'['random.txt']],'folder3'['folder4'['folder5'['1.txt','2.txt','3.txt']]]]]
```

I'd like to essentially make a list which represents a file tree. For example:

```
user

-folder1

--folder2

---random.txt

--1.txt

--blah.txt

-folder3

--folder4

---folder5

----1.txt

----2.txt

----3.txt

-1.jpg

-hey.jpg
```

All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I had tried to explain it as best as I could, but what it boils down to is this. I want the initial list of file paths to be converted into a list that has the structure of a file tree. Instead of having all of these full paths, I'd like them all to be nested based on what is contained in each folder if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html#os.walk) builtin does what you want. You can play around with the output yourself to get it into the format you want.

Comment: Could you possibly give me a quick example? I've tried a few things but haven't successfully gotten it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Resmar was correct, but I'll give some more detail as to how this was done. I asked a similar question after receiving his response and was given the correct answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42031496/4043494

I'll post the actual code when I'm not on mobile.